# Jquery Ajax Serialize data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a form that fetches all the data from database and in order to update the datas that is fetched i need to serialize the data.

```
alert($("form").serialize());
```

and this is the output

```
tid=1&tname=T+Cap&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=1200&tid=2&tname=Super&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=2800&tid=3&tname=Dota+Tees&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=700
```

how to retrieve this data in php in order for me to update the database?

Comment: @MichaelDoye still getting the last values of the $_POST datas. im using this 
$tid = $_POST['tid'];
$tname = $_POST['tname'];
$tsize = $_POST['tsize'];

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine functions `$.submit()` and `$.post()` or `$.ajax()`:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"), 
        data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // show response from the php script
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then in your PHP script you have to read your data from `$_POST` array. E.g.

```
$tid = $_POST['tid'];
```

To debug your incoming $_POST array use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

If you want to send response to your javascript just pack whatever you want into variable and then just use `die(json_encode());`. E.g.:

```
$output = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Success');
die(json_encode($output));
```

It also will be required to add to `$.post()` method attribute:

```
dataType : 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are redefining your $_POST vars. They can not contain the same names/keys as you are sending them over currently. Essentially its like redefining a variable, it will no longer contain its previous value.

```
tid=1&tname=T+Cap&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=1200&tid=2&tname=Super&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=2800&tid=3&tname=Dota+Tees&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=700
```

Notice how you have called `tid` and the other keys multiple times? Instead you would want to give them separate names,or pass an array of values to your PHP.

**Example:**

```
tid=1&tname=T+Cap&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=1200&tid2=2&tname2=Super&tsize2=XS&quantity2=1&tprice2=2800&tid3**=3&tname3=Dota+Tees&tsize3=XS&quantity3=1&tprice3=700
```

Of course there are other ways of doing this as well.

Each key must have a unique identifier, other wise it will overwrite the previously defined $_POST value.

Instead of:

```
tid=1&
tid=2&
tid=3&
```

You would want:

```
tid1=1&
tid2=2&
tid3=3&
```

Comment: i am only getting the last value of the $_POST datas. how to put them into array?

Comment: technically they are already in an array. $_POST is the array. if you var_dump($_POST[]) you will see all of the data displayed in that array.

Comment: Check out what I just added, and see if that helps to make sense of this.

Comment: still the output is the last value that is passed in the $_POST which is the tid=3&tname=Dota+Tees&tsize=XS&quantity=1&tprice=700

Comment: OH! I see what is happening. You are redefining your post vars. Give me one minute and I will explain your problem in the answer section.

Comment: Check the update. Does that explain the problem you are having?

Comment: in my example given. i have 3 tid's 3 tname's and so on. i want is to output all the datas.

Comment: I understand that, but you are redefining each of them. You need to give each of them unique names like:  tid1, tid2, tid3, tname1, tname2, tname3. Make sense?

Comment: If you show your markup and javascript, I can likely easily show you a solution to this problem.    :)

Comment: btw. thanks sir, i found a solution but its kinda slow coz i use pure php. :)

Comment: Well let me know if you want a clientside way of doing it. Show your markup and I'll help.

Comment: ok sir, ill try my best, but for now ill just go with this. i need this for presentation purpose. :) thank you so much for the info sir.

Comment: No problem. Any time. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP, at the top write this and you'll see what's happening.

```
//If method = GET
var_dump($_GET);
//If method = POST
var_dump($_POST);
exit();
```

This will show all variables that are being passed and stop the script so you can review on the page. Then just have your jquery put the response data in a div that you can view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for PHP's parse_str() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php